# Swift2 Ambiguous use of subscript when i run it on device

Tags: xcode, swift, subscript

I have got a problem with my swift code when im going to run my application on my device. When i run it on the simulator everything is fine, but when im going to run it on my device i get two errors.

I get two errors on the last two rows, and it says "ambiguous use of subscript" on both of the lines.

Im running the latest xcode if that is for any help...

```
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "The webpage im getting info from")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in



        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse // method that access information

        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)


                // naming the two variables from json
                if let counter = json["counts"] {

            // It gets an error on both the peopleIn and peopleOut
                    let peopleIn = counter! [0]
                    let peopleOut = counter! [1]
```

Comment: I hope the counter i.e. json["counts"] is a proper array structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json["counts"]` returns `AnyObject`, the compiler has no idea that it's supposed to be an array.

Cast the object to the expected type, at least

```
if let counter = json["counts"] as? [AnyObject] {
```

If the expected type is more specific than `[AnyObject]` cast it to that type.

If `if let` succeeds the associated variable is non-optional, the exclamation mark is not needed.

```
let peopleIn = counter[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me running the application on the device, but now it gives me an error that says: "Error with Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"

Comment: It works perfectly on the simulator but not on the device. How come the simulator can get a good JSON but not the device? Should they not be the same?

Comment: Actually they should be the same. Create a string from the returned data respectively and compare the strings.